# Does git takes into account my .gitattributes for *.vbs text eol=crlf?

Tags: git, vbscript, eol, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

I'm currently working on VBScript (*.vbs) files, meant to be run on Windows only.

I want them to be checkout with CRLF disregarding of how developers have set their `core.autocrlf`. BTW, mine seems set to `false` when running `git config --get core.autocrlf`

So I created a `.gitattributes` file with this:

```
*.vbs text eol=crlf
```

Commited both the files (with their CRLF EOL's) and this `.gitattributes` one.

But now I've done some changes to a file, without changing the EOL's, when I want to see a diff e.g. in `gitk` I have to check *Ignore space change* to properly see the line differences, otherwise the whole file is considered to have changed.

What did I do wrong?

Note: especially here on SO and other forums, I read people saying to use e.g. `*.vbs binary` to avoid Git from altering EOL's - in the same way it's advised to do so on `*.jpg` files in the Git online doc - however `binary` means `-text -diff` and I don't want to (un)set `-diff` because I want to have diffs!!

Comment: You can check all attributes: `git check-attr -a *.vbs`. You can set just `-text` instead of `binary`.

Comment: thanks @phd seems like it did the trick: I only kept `*.vbs -text` in my `.gitattributes` and everything works as I expected now; would you mind to post an answer too? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell Git not to muck about with your files, you must live with the fact that some files have been permanently stored with LF-only line endings and others have been permanently stored with CRLF line endings.

If you tell Git to mess with your files, it will do that not only while extracting (`git checkout`) or adding (`git add`) files to be saved in their permanent format, but also while extracting files for diff purposes.

That's *part* of what you must choose now, because it's clear that you have existing committed copies that have LF-ony line endings.

#### How this all works

The declaration:

```
<pattern> text eol=crlf
```

is, in effect, a command to Git that tells it:

- When you take a file *out* of the freeze-dried format (as stored in the repository and in the index / staging-area, to put it into the work-tree where you can see it and use it), change any newline-only end-of-lines into CRLF end-of-lines.
- When you freeze-dry a file, i.e., store a work-tree file into the index so that it will go *into* the next commit, and it has CRLF line endings, change them to newline-only line-endings.

In other words, you're telling Git: *Please muck about with my files.*  The `eol=...` part tells it *how* to muck with the files.  The *`pattern`* part of the line tells Git *which* files, and the `text` directive tells Git: *These are text files, so they show up OK on my screen in diffs, and you should mess with them.*

If you use `binary` as an attribute, you're telling Git: *These are binary files, so they don't show up OK on my screen in diffs, and you should not mess with them at all.*

As [phd noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950003/does-git-takes-into-account-my-gitattributes-for-vbs-text-eol-crlf#comment100440490_56950003), you can use `-text` to say *do not mess with them* without *also* saying *they cannot be displayed*.  But saying *do not mess with them* means *do not mess with them*, and that includes when extracting the dehydrated contents in order to make diffs.

*All* of Git's messing with files occurs during either the rehydrating phase, when a freeze-dried file is turned back into a usable one, or the freeze-drying phase, when a regular file is turned into one that can be stored inside Git.  Furthermore, *all* of Git's built-in modification processes for text files store them inside Git with LF-only line endings.  If these `*.vbs` files *must* have CRLFs inside them while stored inside Git,<sup>1</sup> they must not be modified on the way in, and therefore you cannot use any of Git's built-in modification options.

If the files *may* (are permitted to) have LF-only line endings while stored inside Git, you *can* use the built-in modifications.  If they *must* have CRLF line endings when in your work-tree (or any form in which you can see and work with them), *and* existing committed copies stored inside Git already have LF-only line endings, then you *must* choose to have Git make changes to the files on their way in and out of the freeze-dried formats, because no existing freeze-dried file stored inside Git now can ever be changed.<sup>2</sup>

If you can live with existing freeze-dried copies that *don't* have CRLF line endings, staying that way when they come back out, while new files get stored inside Git with their CRLF line endings and keep their CRLF line endings during the copies in and out, you can use `-text` (or use nothing at all<sup>3</sup>) and just not have Git mess with them.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not clear to me why this would ever be required, since only Git can read Git's freeze-dried stored files.  I put it this way because it's easier to think about it this way, and *then* move from "it absolutely must be done this way" to "I would prefer to do it this way" as you relax your constraints.

<sup>2</sup>You do, of course, have the option of taking some existing repository and *transforming it* into a new and different repository, with new and different commits, that have the files in some other form.  You can do this over an entire repository, using `git filter-branch ... --all`, or some subset of a repository.  The upside of doing this is that you end up with a "clean" repository, as if you had, long ago, been following whatever practice you establish now.  The downside is that you must get everyone who has a clone of the original repository to switch to using the replacement commits you come up with today.

<sup>3</sup>The original concept for Git was that it was to preserve, forever, all files exactly as they appeared in the index at commit time.  That concept remains, but the introduction of these modifications—of "smudging" files as they come out of the index into the work-tree, then "cleaning" them as they go back in for the next commit—enables Windows users, who demand CRLF line endings, to get along with Linux users, who demand LF-only line endings.  But it also introduces this clumsy situation in which Git must now know which files *should* get messed-with—which ones are "text"—and which files should not, because they're "binary".  Eliminate the mucking-about with your data, and you eliminate the need to describe which files get which treatment.

Comment: thanks for that great (long) explanation although I found it really tricky to understand, because - although I'm using git for years now - I'm not sure I fully understand this concept of "freeze-fried format" that would be different whether the file is in "repository" vs "index" vs "staging-area" vs "work-tree"...? why does it has to be so complicated... o.O

Comment: Once you commit a file into Git, it's saved there *forever*. That happens for *every* version of *every* file. To keep this from growing really big really fast, Git stores the files in a special, compressed, and read-only form that can only be used *by* Git. And, because it's read-only, this means that Git can actually just *share* the copy of that file with every other commit that uses the same version of the file. But because these files are *only* useful to Git itself, Git has to extract them somewhere, to let you work on/with them. That's the *work-tree*.

Comment: As for the index/staging area, that's two words for one thing. The three active copies—`HEAD` version, index/staging-area version, and work-tree version—is a Git weirdness that Git forces you to understand. (Other version control systems don't bother with this intermediate "index" thing.) There are many reasons that you have to know about the index: for instance, "tracked files" vs "untracked files" is literally defined by the presence or absence of a copy of the file in the index.